# Tomtom Maps sdk for android failed to load tile

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I'm trying to add `TomTom` maps to my android application that is built with `Kotlin`, but it gives me the error `Tomtom Maps SDK for android failed to load tile` and shows an empty map as shown in the image below :

[image: tomtom maps failed to load tiles]

And here are my files and detailed configurations I'm using:

- In the project level Gradle file I have :

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.tomtom.com:8443/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

- In the app level Gradle file I have :

```
    dependencies {
    implementation("com.tomtom.online:sdk-maps:2.4244")
}
```

- And I've added the `APK` to the `AndroidManifests` file :

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="OnlineMaps.Key"
        android:value="<my-Key-here>" />
```

- Also, the map fragment is added to the .XML files :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.tomtom.online.sdk.map.MapFragment"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- And finally, here is the Kotlin code used to start the map :

```
    //lateinit late initialization of non-null type variables
    private lateinit var map: TomtomMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment) as MapFragment
        mapFragment.getAsyncMap(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    }


    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 101
    }
    private fun setUpMap() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) {
                location ->
            if (location != null){
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                val balloon = SimpleMarkerBalloon("You are Here")
                map.addMarker(MarkerBuilder(currentLatLng).markerBalloon(balloon))
                map.centerOn(CameraPosition.builder(currentLatLng).zoom(7.0).build())

            }

        }
    }


    override fun onMapReady(@NonNull tomtomMap: TomtomMap) {
        this.map = tomtomMap
        setUpMap()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible points to check:

- Your API key is not valid. Please check your API key by calling a raw TomTom Maps endpoint: [https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/0/0/0.png?key=your_api_key](https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/0/0/0.png?key=%3Cyour_api_key%3E) and if you are not able to see the map tile image - register your new API key by going to [TomTom Developer Portal](https://developer.tomtom.com/user/me/apps/add) and check again.
- Your API key is placed in the wrong place inside AndroidManifest.xml file. Make sure that it's placed inside the `<application>` tag, next to `<activity>` tag.

Comment: https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/0/0/0.png?key=your_api_key  this api with my key is working fine on the webbrowser.
I also checked that MAPS -KEY is placed properly. but still map not showing on the device